Type deduction for a std::vector of std::pair
I'm fairly new to the nuances of template type deduction in C++, and one of the issues I've recently faced is the inability to deduce types for nested containers.
This example uses std::vector and std::pair:
int main() {
    std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> vec_of_pairs{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}; // Deduction does not work
    std::vector vec_of_numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}; // Deduction works
    std::pair pair = {1, 2.5}; // Deduction works
    return 0;
}

Is something like this possible to solve with a template deduction guide (see example below), or does it go beyond the scope of such mechanism? Is it even possible at all?
template <typename T1, typename T2>
std::vector(std::initializer_list<std::pair<T1, T2>>) -> std::vector<std::pair<T1, T2>>;


Not the exact syntax you want, but std::vector vec_of_pairs{std::pair{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}; works fine without a manual deduction guide (demo)

With your template deduction guide, it is possible if you move it to std namespace, even though it is not recommended.

You can't add a deduction guide to vector since it lives in namespace std and adding a deduction guide to std is not allowed.
You only need to specify the nested type once in the initializer list to get the entire list to be deduced to have elements of that type.  That lets you use
std::vector vec_of_pairs{std::pair{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};

to get the vector of pairs to be deduced for you.
